# How to remove duplicate word in dictionary (python)

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary called top_topics that has the following words (example):

```
{0: ['soccer'], 1: ['football'], 2: ['hockey'], 3: ['basketball'], 4: ['football']}
```

I would like to remove football from the dictionary but haven't been able to figure out a way how. I created a loop that in my mind would fix the issue but it hasn't:

```
for key, value in topic_keywords.items():
    for item in value:
        if item not in topic_keywords.values():
            unique_dict[key] = value
topic_keywords = unique_dict
```

but I still get the same results. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: What's the significance of the `key`-value being an integer? Is there a reason why you can't simply swap them around?

Comment: How do you decide which occurrence should be removed? Key 1 or key 4? Or do you want to remove all occurrences of duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good use-case for a *set*. You also need to allow for the fact your values (in the original dictionary) are lists.

```
data = {0: ['soccer'], 1: ['football'], 2: ['hockey'], 3: ['basketball'], 4: ['football']}

new_data = dict()
values = set()

for k, v in data.items():
    for _v in v:
        if _v not in values:
            new_data.setdefault(k, []).append(_v)
            values.add(_v)

print(new_data)
```

**Output:**

```
{0: ['soccer'], 1: ['football'], 2: ['hockey'], 3: ['basketball']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `enumerate` over the dictionary and use the index to check if the value is not in a slice of the dictionary values and was inserted previously

```
top_topics = {0: ['soccer'], 1: ['football'], 2: ['hockey'], 3: ['basketball'], 4: ['football']}
values = list(top_topics.values())
new_top_topics = {}
for i, (k, v) in enumerate(top_topics.items()):
    if v not in values[:i]:
        new_top_topics[k] = v
```

or check if the value is already in the new dictionary

```
top_topics = {0: ['soccer'], 1: ['football'], 2: ['hockey'], 3: ['basketball'], 4: ['football']}
new_top_topics = {}
for i, (k, v) in enumerate(top_topics.items()):
    if v not in new_top_topics.values():
        new_top_topics[k] = v
```

With dict comprehensions

```
top_topics = {0: ['soccer'], 1: ['football'], 2: ['hockey'], 3: ['basketball'], 4: ['football']}
values = list(top_topics.values())
top_topics = {k: v for i, (k, v) in enumerate(top_topics.items()) if v not in values[:i]}
```

Results

```
{0: ['soccer'], 1: ['football'], 2: ['hockey'], 3: ['basketball']}
```